# Help needed to identify the seeds

Tags: flavor, food-identification, seeds

I've received the following seeds from one relatives, used in our for some recipes. I want to know what this seeds are.

They taste bitter like fenugreek seeds, and the person who bought it calls it **Irani Seeds**.

Any help would be appriciated.

[image: Seeds]

Answer (score 1):

They also look like fenugreek seeds, and **Irani Methi** is fenugreek. Fenugreek has a very typical perfume when crushed and/or cooked, that would also help in identifying them

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried to google **Irani Methi** but the results shown are like typical fenugreek seeds. but this seeds have slight different texture (smooth) and shape (like kidney). Can you help with that.

Comment: One more thing, they have bought it from Dubai (if it helps)

Comment: The smell of the crushed or cooked spice is very typical, but hard to transmit over the internet... If it smells like fenugreek, with the other similarities, I'd say it is fenugreek.

Comment: @Tuna Here is your version: https://healthunlocked.com/diabetesindia/posts/133677662/irani-methi-fenugreek-seeds

Comment: @remco, yes, smells are usually hard to transmit over the internet. But fenugreek is one of the few that is easy, at least to those who know what maple syrup smells like, because the 2 things smell a *lot* alike.

Comment: @LorelC.: Interesting, I've never associated the smell of fenugreek with the smell of maple syrup. But then: I use a fair amount of fenugreek, and maple syrup only every now and again.